# How to format phone characters using using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, jsp

I have a string for example "123456789". I want this string to replace like below "XXX-XX-6789".

I have achieved "123-45-6789" using normal javascript using below code

```
function mask(str, textbox, loc, delim) {

    var value = document.getElementById("num").value;
    var locs = loc.split(',');
    for (var i = 0; i <= locs.length; i++) {
        for (var k = 0; k <= str.length; k++) {
            if (k == locs[i]) {
                if (str.substring(k, k + 1) != delim) {
                    str = str.substring(0, k) + delim + str.substring(k, str.length)
                }

            }

        }

    }
    textbox.value = str
}
```

But I'm not able to get the required format as "XXX-XX-6789". So can anyone suggest the solution for this and help me..:(

I'm not using jQuery and I want to use in normal JS.

Comment: whether the length of the string will always be a contant

Comment: @Arun check my answer dude

Comment: Check this [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/stchd16t/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex solution that is built in with JavaScript. It is much faster than any algorithm you have brother

```
var stringSample = "234443444";

stringSample.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1-$2-$3')

stringSample.replace(/(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, 'XXX-XX-$3')
```

Comment: Didn't you read `I have achieved "123-45-6789" using normal javascript using below code. But I'm not able to get the required format as "XXX-XX-6789"`

Comment: @Tushar, please check my answer ;)

Comment: @AllanChua but this will fit only for exact 9 digits.. and I also tried this but I want this when its is 6 digit or any else or more.. SO i thought of making array and do it but I cant achieve it in loop as replace not working ..

Answer (score 1):

As you already said that you achieve this `123-45-6789` now you wanna `XXX-XX-6789` then just use below instruction after your string which u get from your js function

store return js string in str and use below to get your string.

```
var str = '123-45-6789';

var temp = 'XXX-XX-'+str.split('-')[2];
```

Comment: This works here and thanks but one thing when I reduce the str to 4 digits then its showing "XXX-XX-undefined" which is not recommended right?

Comment: reduced the str to 4 digit means ????? can u elaborate some more so that we can fix it

Comment: If I have var str = '123-4', at that time I'm getting the output as ""XXX-XX-undefined" so how can fix this???